# Export Non-executable jar in Eclipse with Reference Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar, export

I have a project in Eclipse which I would like to export into a jar. However, this code is only generic helper code I use on many projects and would like to have wrapped up nicely, so I *do not* want to create an executable jar. My code relies on two referenced libraries, but it seems that the non-executable jar export feature in Eclipse does not repackage references jars. Is there a way to accomplish this in Eclipse, or with some third-party tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fat Jar Eclipse Plugin : http://fjep.sourceforge.net/